# Why automapper get error when I map model?

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

I have some trouble with mapping. When I tried to map the model I took the next error:

**Error mapping types.**

> **Mapping types: TeamModel -> Team Basketball.Core.Models.TeamModel -> Basketball.Core.Entities.Team**
>
> **Type Map configuration: TeamModel -> Team Basketball.Core.Models.TeamModel -> Basketball.Core.Entities.Team**
>
> **Destination Member: Location**

I try to mapp the next models:

```
public class TeamModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Region { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public bool InPlayoff { get; set; }
    public int Wins { get; set; }
    public int Loses { get; set; }        
}

public class Team
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public bool InPlayoff { get; set; }
    public int Wins { get; set; }
    public int Loses { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

And my mapper configuration:

```
 CreateMap<TeamModel, Team>()
   .ForMember(x => x.Id, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Id))
   .ForMember(x => x.Name, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Name))
   .ForMember(x => x.InPlayoff, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.InPlayoff))
   .ForMember(x => x.Wins, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Wins))
   .ForMember(x => x.Loses, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Loses));
```

I no need to map location, region, and country, but if I add:

```
 .ForPath(x => x.Location.Name, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Location))
 .ForPath(x => x.Location.Region, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Region))
 .ForPath(x => x.Location.Country, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Country))
```

Mapper is working, but how I said I do not need it. How to solve this error? Where I make a mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ignore this property like this:

```
CreateMap<TeamModel, Team>()
   .ForMember(x => x.Id, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Id))
   .ForMember(x => x.Name, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Name))
   .ForMember(x => x.InPlayoff, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.InPlayoff))
   .ForMember(x => x.Wins, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Wins))
   .ForMember(x => x.Loses, x => x.MapFrom(y => y.Loses))
   .ForMember(x => x.Location, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

Comment: Thank you for helping

Answer (score -1):

Ignore the properties from the automapper that you do not need.

```
.ForPath(x => x.Location.Name, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForPath(x => x.Location.Region, opt => opt.Ignore())
.ForPath(x => x.Location.Country, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can you explain what you posted and why you hope it helps, or is it just a guess?

Comment: It should the ignore the properties that OP doesn't need while mapping. Am I missing something badly?